# How to configure URL token in yii2 rest UrlRule

Tags: yii2, restful-url

I just created a yii2 rest API but some of the endpoint created are not working as expected.
when i do http://localhost/v1/countries I get a response but when i do http://localhost/v1/countries/AU i get a  404 error. I think the problem is with the token but i don't know how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

class CountryController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Country';
}

<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\models;



/**
 * This is the model class for table "country".
 *
 * @property string $code
 * @property string $name
 * @property int $population
 */
class Country extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'country';
    }
    
    public static function primaryKey() { 
        return ['code']; 
        
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['code', 'name'], 'required'],
            [['population'], 'integer'],
            [['code'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 52],
            [['code'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'code' => 'Code',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'population' => 'Population',
        ];
    }
}
 config file
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
      
                
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'controller' => ['v1/default', 'v1/country'],
                     'tokens' => [ '{id}' => 'id:\\w+' ],
                    //'pluralize'=>false,
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'GET,POST,PUT index' => 'index',
                    ],
                        
                ],

                            
             ],
        ],
     

GET /countries: working
HEAD /countries: return status 200 empty message
POST /countries: working
GET /countries/AU: not working 404 error
HEAD /countries/AU: not working 404 error
PATCH /countries/AU: not working 404 error
PUT /countries/AU: not working 404 error
DELETE /countries/AU: not working 404 error
OPTIONS /countries: return status 200 (null)
OPTIONS /countries/AU: not working 404 error
```

Comment: I think this is not a problem with the token since all methods are covered, even `index`, so that means when you call `GET /countries` parsing token. Do you have a `AU` as an `ID` in your column? Usually we parse as an integer number of the record. Try something like `GET /countries/1`

Comment: And change `'tokens' => [ '{id}' => 'id:\\w+' ],` to `'tokens' => [ '{id}' => 'id:\\d+' ],`

Comment: By documentation it says: `List of tokens that should be replaced for each pattern. The keys are the token names, and the values are the corresponding replacements.` You can try this: `'tokens' => [ '{code}' => 'code:\\w+' ],`.